# Writing to a file in a servlet

Tags: java, file, servlets

I am working in a **servlet** and has this code :

```
public void doPost(blah blah){

   response.setContentType("text/html");

    String datasent = request.getParameter("dataSent");
    System.out.println(datasent);

    try{

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:/xyz.txt");
        writer.write("hello");


        System.out.println("I wrote");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    response.getWriter().write("I am from server");

}
```

But everytime it is throwing an error saying Access Denied..
Even when there is no lock on that file and there is no file whose name is **C:/xyz.txt**

what should I do?
;(

```
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xyz.txt (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
at test.TestServlet.doPost(TestServlet.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:237)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Did you try changing your path to : - `D:/xyz.txt`?

Comment: yeah i tried everything? every time it is saying access denied.But the same code works in core java

Comment: I presume you're running in windows with full admin rights and not trying to write somewhere you're not allowed?  You're using Tomcat - correct?  Are you running from within an IDE or a deployed WAR?

Comment: i tried both.................even then it throws exception

Comment: It says "access is denied". How exactly is that unclear? Fix the access rights at OS level. This is not a Java problem.

Answer (score 5):

Try close FileWriter:

```
writer.close();
```

I imagine what happens: One thread in Tomcat creates the file and terminates but not closes its handle, so from file system view file lock is not released. Another thread tries to open it for write but OS still cannot grant write access to the file, because it already has one pending.

This is called resource leak: Garbage Collector does not release resources allocated by programmer manually (here IO handle)

Answer (score 0):

try looking at this [site](http://csis.pace.edu/~wolf/servlets/Java%20Servlets%20and%20Access%20Databases.html) seems like thats what your looking for (scroll down some ways)

Comment: how this is related to my question..........that is just printing the stuff on the the browser.............that's it

Answer (score -1):

During this process, don't open the file.Try as below :

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:/xyz.txt", true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
out.write("your text");
out.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

The exception shows that it is of FileNotFound Exception. Please try to make new file first.
Try with following code.

```
File file = File file("c:/xyz.txt");
if(!file.exists()){  // this will return boolean {true} if file exists.
   file.createNewFile(); // create new empty file.
}
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:/xyz.txt", true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
out.write("your text");
out.close();
```

Ok no issues.. try to figure out it using different Readers and Writers.

```
    String currentExecutablePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String rootPath = currentExecutablePath + "xyz.txt";
    File file = new File(rootPath);
    ServletOutputStream op = res.getOutputStream(); 
    if(file.exists()){
        int length = 0;
        res.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        res.setContentLength((int) file.length());

        byte[] bbuf = new byte[1000];
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));            
        while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
            op.write(bbuf, 0, length);
        }
    }
```