# How do you create a file on Tomcat server from within a Servlet's doPost() method?

Tags: java, servlets, io

I am trying to save a String, containing data from an http post request, to a new file in a /database directory on my server.

```
public class TestIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File newFile = new File("database.txt");
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(newFile);
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
            printWriter.println("test");

            fileWriter.close();
            printWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

makes a file database.txt in the project root directory with the text "test" just fine. But,

```
@WebServlet("/TestIO")
public class TestIO extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //doGet
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            File newFile = new File("database.txt");
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(newFile);
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
            printWriter.println("test");

            fileWriter.close();
            printWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

does nothing. No file created, no errors thrown.

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of and find online. Tried using java.io.File and java.io.FileWriter. Tried just making a blank file through IDE then using PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("test.json"); out.println("<string data>"). Among other things.

My last guess is to send the data to an entity bean and try creating a file from there, but I'd appreciate some help...been at it for hours.

Comment: they mean is read the stackoverflow help center then **edit your question with examples of what you tried and why it doesn't work** otherwise this will be closed very quickly and then promptly deleted most likely!

Comment: also learn to search for existing questions that meet your criteria before you ask duplicate questions! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978635/writing-to-a-file-in-a-servlet

Comment: @Jarrod Updated question. Hopefully now it catches less flack. Thanks for the link, but I came across that one already. I don't get that error thrown and I close my writers. I think I'm having trouble because I'm not getting ANY errors...apparently writers don't always throw them because they are PrintStreams.

Comment: Where are you looking for the file? Have you tried using an absolute path?

Comment: @Sotirios Thanks for the help and sticking with the poorly phrased question. You were right about an incorrect absolute path being the culprit. By using EJP's suggestion about using ServletContext.getRealPath() I discovered that my database.txt files were being created in dot-prefixed directories. I (foolishly) have my Finder settings to hide dot-prefixed directories and their contents, so I, quite amateurishly, kept thinking the files were not being created on my system at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrintWriter` swallows exceptions so you may have missed those by not calling `checkError().`

However if you also tried `FileWriter` and got no exceptions, the answer is that the file was indeed created - just not where you expected. Have a look in the Tomcat `bin` directory for example. If you want it created in a path within the web-app you will have to use `ServletContext.getRealPath()` and friends.

If on the other hand what you're getting is an *empty* file, the reason is here:

```
fileWriter.close();
printWriter.close();
```

This is incorrect. You're closing the `FileWriter` without giving the `PrintWriter` a chance to flush, and when you close the `PrintWriter` it tries to flush and swallows the exception. Remove the first of these two closes altogether.

Comment: Thank you very much. The ServletContext.getRealPath() part helped me find my problem, which did happen to be the way I was specifying the path. After correcting the path I tested having both fileWriter.close(); and printWriter.close(); again to see if that had any effect, out of curiosity. Nothing changed, but I will keep this in mind for future use so still super helpful :)